# RESTful Strings matcher in Java

Tags: java, url, rest

I'm looking for a Java library that evaluates REST-style URLs. Something like:

```
public Result evaluate(String url, String pattern);
```

The pattern would be something like:

*/users/{userId}/photos/{photoId}.html*

The result must include:

- indication if the url matches pattern
- the actual values of the url variables *{userId}* and *{photoId}*

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "evaluate", do you mean some kind of unification or pattern matching by which the `url` string is matched against the `pattern` string, mapping the placeholders in the pattern to the corresponding substrings in the URL?

If so, [the Restlet library](http://www.restlet.org/)'s [`Template` class](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/jse/api/org/restlet/routing/Template.html) may suffice. In particular, look at [`Template#parse(String, Map<String, Object>)`](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/jse/api/org/restlet/routing/Template.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29). That looks close to fitting your needs, though the documentation is a little vague as to what constitutes the input and output.

Comment: Thanks to your response, looking at the javadocs I did find the "URI Template Specification" term, which I didn't know. So I did search for "java uri template" on Google and I found some other useful options as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might already know about this, but JBoss RestEasy http://jboss.org/resteasy 
project handles such cases and should have classes to deal with such cases. I believe its open source and therefore you can see if its helpful

Answer (score 1):

- **Jersey (JAX-RS) RI**: (always maintained). http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.14/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/uri/UriTemplate.html
- **Handy URI Templates**: https://github.com/damnhandy/Handy-URI-Templates
- **wo-furi**: A tool for URI pattern matching using the URI Templates notation. (last release: Feb 2010). http://code.google.com/p/wo-furi/